# Putting arguments into a char array, code explanation

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I'd really want to know what is going on in a following piece of code. In function parse, what does                    `*line++ = '\0';`  mean? Is it equal to `line[i] = '\0'` and `i++;` ?

Next, what is this `*argv++ = line;` doing? How can it assign whole variable line to I assume first argv[0], then argv[1] etc? Wouldn't that be too long?

Next while is just skipping through line array till it reaches a word.

Now, after the parse function is done, what does calling argv and argv* do? is *argv the first argument?

Thanks in advance, I really need to understand that : (

```
void  parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') {  
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';  

          *argv++ = line;      

          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
               line++; 
     }
     *argv = '\0';   
}
```

and in main:

```
 char  line[1024];      
 char  *argv[64];    
 while (1) {  
      ....
      gets(line); 
      ...
      parse(line, argv);
```

Comment: Note that using `gets()` in a program is dangerous; you have no control over whether the buffer is overflowed.  The first Internet worm (the 'Morris' worm) exploited `gets()` as one of its ways of propagating.  The C11 standard dropped `gets()`; it is no longer a part of standard C.  You should assume it doesn't exist, or that it contains `abort()`, and should never ever use `gets()`.  Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `*line++ = '\0';` is straight-forward.  As some people have noted, the `++` operator has a higher precedence than the `*` operator, so the expression could be parenthesized as `*(line++) = '\0';`.

The `line++` operator evaluates to the current value of `line` and then increments the value in line.  The `*line++` therefore evaluates to the character that `line` currently points at.  The assignment means that a null byte `'\0'` is assigned to the current position, and `line` is incremented past this position.  It is a shorthand for:

```
*line = '\0';
line++;
```

In the question, you ask:

> What does `*line++ = '\0';` mean? Is it equal to `line[i] = '\0'` and `i++;`?

The first part has been addressed.  The second part is more or less accurate; strictly, it only applies if `i = 0;` is assigned first (so `i` would be `1` after the increment), or if you always used `i` to index `line` without changing the value of `line` itself.

Note that the line `*argv = '\0';` line would be more conventionally written `*argv = NULL;` or `*argv = 0;` since `*argv` is a `char *`, not a character.  It is not formally incorrect; `'\0'` is an integer constant zero, and therefore a valid null pointer constant, but it is aconventional to write it that way.

In the given code:

```
void parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') {
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';
```

There's no need to zap the leading blanks; it would be sufficient to write `line++`.  It's also tempting to suggest the use of `isspace()` or `isblank()`.  I observe that input from `gets()` (which is shown in the `main()` program and should not be used) never contains a newline, so the newline test is redundant in this context.

```
          *argv++ = line;

          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
               line++;
     }
     *argv = '\0';
}
```

The idea is that if the input line is:

```
arguments   about   the  meaning of life
```

then afterwards, you'd be able to make all of the following assertions safely:

```
assert(strcmp(argv[0], "arguments") == 0);
assert(strcmp(argv[1], "about") == 0);
assert(strcmp(argv[2], "the") == 0);
assert(strcmp(argv[3], "meaning") == 0);
assert(strcmp(argv[4], "of") == 0);
assert(strcmp(argv[5], "life") == 0);
assert(argv[6] == 0);
```

Given that you're chopping up the input line, it might be sensible to consider the POSIX [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) function or Microsoft's [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) (or, if the worst comes to the worst, [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html), but using `strtok()` requires extreme caution — no code calling this function can be using `strtok()` at the time the call is made, for example).

```
void parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
    char *token = line;
    char *extra;

    while ((token = strtok_r(token, " \t\n", &extra)) != 0)
    {
        *argv++ = token;
        token = 0;
    }
    *argv = 0;
}
```

It might also be sensible to redesign the function to report how many (non-null) arguments there are:

```
int parse(char *line, char **p_argv)
{
    char *token = line;
    char *extra;
    char **argv = p_argv;

    while ((token = strtok_r(token, " \t\n", &extra)) != 0)
    {
        *argv++ = token;
        token = 0;
    }
    *argv = 0;
    return argv - p_argv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*line++ = '\0'` is equal to:

```
*line = '\0';
line++;
```

It is used to null-terminate a string, as it should be in C.

The `*argv++ = line` is meant to parse the next argument from the arguments supplied in the `char **argv` (pointer to the `char` array).

Comment: See my answer.  `*line++ = '\0';` is effectively a shorthand for `*line = '\0'; line++;`

Comment: And the compiler will complain about 'value computed is not used' because of the `*` in front of `*line++;`, a `*` which was noticeably absent from my comment.

Comment: Right, now it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * line
```

means that you get a pointer to a char. So let's make clear that

```
*line
```

would get you the actual character  (this is called dereferencing)
So what `*line++ = '\0';` does is:

```
*line = '\0';
line++;
```

So it is the same as `line[i++] = '\0'` .

Exactly the same applies to *argv++ = line;

**Notice** that *line++ is completely different than (*line)++ .

Answer (score 0):

Actually since the assignment operator has higher precedence over the `++` then `*line++ = '\0';` actually equals to:

```
*line = '\0';
*line++;          // Increment the pointer in sizeof(char)
```

Now, regarding you question about argv, then please note that it is defined as an array of strings.
The type of `*argv` is then `char*` which match the type of line. The assignment `*argv++ = line` means placing the address pointed by line to *argv (and not a full copy of the string in line) so there is no risk of writing too much into it (unless argv does not contain enough elements to hold the **number** of lines).
Finally, the statement `*argv = '\0'` is probably there to mark that we just reached the end of the array of strings, in a similar way end of string is marked in C.

Comment: The precedence of `++` is very high; the precedence of `=` is very low.  Your first statement ("since the assignment operator has higher precedence over the `++`") therefore is wrong, even though your subsequent explanation of what happens is correct.

Comment: Jonathan is correct. Getting the value of the result is sequenced before updating the operand.

Answer (score -1):

The `++` operator has higher precedence than `*` so

`*line++` will lead to pointer `line` being inceremented first.

```
line++;
```

Then

```
*line++ = '\0';
```

`argv` is a double pointer here and `*argv` will be pointing to `line`.

```
*argv++ = line
```

Same explanation as above

Comment: I still don't understand it, what would argv would look like for line for example 'test two third' and how would it work? First while would make *argv[0] point to 'test two third', then second to 'two third' and third to 'third' or am I wrong?

Comment: The explanation of what happens is not accurate.